# Meaning of "dome"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, poetry

Oscar Wilde writes in his poem *La Mer*:

> The shattered storm has left its trace
>   Upon this huge and **heaving dome**,
>   For the thin threads of yellow foam
>   Float on the waves like ravelled lace.

What is **heaving dome** here?
Is it a sky dome or a sea surface?
Can you say **heaving** about sky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oscar Wilde's *La Mer* (The Sea) is describing **heavy weather**.

**Heaving** seas occur during rough weather where huge **swells** occur [**here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBM7NgMhg90)
The sea can appear to create **domes** (rounded tops)

Seas **heave**
A person breathing hard has a **heaving** chest

it has the sense of **undulating** motion

To understand

> **thin threads of yellow foam**

**white caps** (when swells break over the top) form when wind speed exceeds 20mph, misting occurs above 30mph.

The general description is of a **very wind day** on the matter.

Comment: Did I understand it right, that dome is just an upper part of a huge wave? And when "yellow foam float on the waves" it means that foam float on the lesser waves that ripple upon the dome?

Comment: I would say that the **yellow foam** is either the **froth** that floats on the waves (created by the wind) and gets blown around, or the spray off of a white cap (the colour can change depending on what's in the water) and the **dome** is the huge swell of an unbroken wave.